# Spotify Web API returns 404 with valid show id

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

I'm trying out the WebAPI and have run into a snag that doesn't make sense.

In the developer console a search for the episode list for show id `4rOoJ6Egrf8K2IrywzwOMk` returns a list.

Even accessing the given URL (https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/4rOoJ6Egrf8K2IrywzwOMk/episodes) in the browser returns the episode list, if I'm logged into my spotify account.

I'm not sure what's broken in my code.

```
async function listPodcastEpisodes(id) {
  const access_token = await getAuth()
  const api_url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/${id}/episodes`
  console.log(api_url)
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(api_url, setAxiosOptions(access_token))
    return response.data
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(err?.response?.data, null, 2)}`)
  }
}

listPodcastEpisodes(process.argv[2])
  .then(x => console.log(x))
```

This code returns:

```
$ node getInfo.js 4rOoJ6Egrf8K2IrywzwOMk
https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/4rOoJ6Egrf8K2IrywzwOMk/episodes
Error: {
  "error": {
    "status": 404,
    "message": "non existing id"
  }
}
undefined
```

The other functions and variable settings:

```
const auth = `${process.env.ID}:${process.env.SECRET}`
const auth_encoded = Buffer.from(auth, 'utf-8').toString("base64")

function setAxiosOptions(data) {
  return {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${data}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
}

async function getAuth () {
  try {
    const token_url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';
    const data = qs.stringify({'grant_type':'client_credentials'});
    const response = await axios.post(token_url, data, {
      headers: { 
        'Authorization': `Basic ${auth_encoded}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
      }
    })

    return response.data.access_token;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated but GET requests do not need a content-type header since they have no request body. The only other thing I'd do is URL-encode the ID, eg `\`https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/${encodeURIComponent(id)}/episodes\``

Comment: Yeah that's a good point about the content type header. There isn't a necessity to encode the id, it's purely alphanumeric.

Comment: Since it comes from the command line args, you can never be too sure

Comment: It didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you may need to include the `market` parameter.

I found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/1577) on the official Web API repo describing the same problem you're experiencing. This issue is referenced by [this issue](https://github.com/vdesabou/alfred-spotify-mini-player/issues/351), where GitHub user MrXyfir posts [their workaround](https://github.com/vdesabou/alfred-spotify-mini-player/issues/351#issuecomment-766410168):

> Edit: For anyone else who ends up with this issue, the solution for me was to set the market param. https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/4rOoJ6Egrf8K2IrywzwOMk/episodes?market=US

Comment: I saw this previously and did not appropriately consider it. This time I took a closer look at my code and was able to fix it. Thanks for the suggestion. It made me look closer and I was able to get it working. The 'market' query appears to be critical. The code returned the expected data when I added it to my search url.